# How to pass variable objects to multiple javascript popup forms

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4

This is my first serious foray into javascript/ajax.

Overview:
I have an index page listing multiple records, each on different rows.  For each record I have a link which pops open a small javascript window which contains a symfony form.  All goes well, with the exception that I can't figure out how to pass the popup javascript the object Id of each record.  Here's what I have:

Starting with the Action:

```
public function executeTrackReferrals(sfWebRequest $request){
       $userId = $this->getUser()->getId();       
       $this->pager = new sfDoctrinePager('referral', sfConfig::get('app_pager'));
       $this->pager->setQuery(Doctrine_Core::getTable('Referral_submissions')->getUsersSubmissions($userId));
       $this->pager->setPage($request->getParameter('page', 1));
       $this->pager->init();}
```

Main index page:

```
<?php 
    include_partial('<a bunch of other includes >');
    include_partial('referral/rtsIndex', array('pager' => $pager));  
?>
```

_rtsIndex partial:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($pager->getResults() as $r => $referral): ?>
<?php 
    $referralObject = Doctrine_Core::getTable('referral')->getReferralObjectById($referral->getId()); 
    $submissionObject = Doctrine_Core::getTable('referral_submissions')->getObjectByReferralId($referralObject->getId()); 
?> 
<TR VALIGN=TOP> 
            <td WIDTH=10% ALIGN="center" class="_7">
            <P ALIGN=CENTER>
                <script type='text/javascript'>
                    $('.popup_changestatus').click(function(){
                    // put the row id into the hidden field in the popup
                      var rowId = $(this).parent().find('span.row_id').html();
                      $('test').val(rowId);
                    fg_popup_form("fg_formContainer","fg_form_InnerContainer","fg_backgroundpopup");
                    return false;
                    });
                </script>

                <a href="#" class="popup_changestatus">
                    <?php echo utilities::getStatusCode($submissionObject->getCandidateStatus()); ?>
                </a>
                <span class="row_id" style="display: none">
                    <?php echo $referral->getId() ?>
                </span>

            </P>
        </td>
</TR>
</table>
```

the Javascript popup form code mentioned above, includes this line:

```
<?php  include_partial('referral/changeStatusCodeForm'); ?>
```

The above line renders the actual symfony form:

_changeStatusCodeForm partial:

```
<?php
$object = new referral_submissionsForm(<this is where I need to pass an ID for each popup form>);
echo $object;
?>
```

Can anyone steer me in the right direction?

If interested in the actual javascript code, it's a pretty nifty open source popup:
http://www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/simple-modal-popup-contact-form.html

EDIT:
Here is the contents of contactform-code.php:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/project/misc/simple-popup-form-1/scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/project/misc/simple-popup-form-1/scripts/fg_ajax.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/project/misc/simple-popup-form-1/scripts/fg_moveable_popup.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/project/misc/simple-popup-form-1/scripts/fg_form_submitter.js'></script>
<div id='fg_formContainer'>
    <div id="fg_container_header">
        <div id="fg_box_Title">Change Status</div>
        <div id="fg_box_Close"><a href="javascript:fg_hideform('fg_formContainer','fg_backgroundpopup');">Close(X)</a></div>
    </div>

    <div id="fg_form_InnerContainer">
    <form id='contactus' action='javascript:fg_submit_form()' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
    <input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />
    <div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>
    <div id='fg_server_errors' class='error'></div>
    <div class='container'>

        <?php 
//        $form = new referral_submissionsForm();
          include_partial('referral/changeStatusCodeForm'); 
        ?>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't directly use `Doctrine_Core` into your model. The best way here, is to make a `leftJoin` on your 2 tables when you pass the query to the pager. Then, in your template, you just fetch the relation (like `$object->getRelation()`).

Regarding to your problem, you should pass the ID when building the `<div id='fg_formContainer'>` since it's the content of your popup. The part come from this file: `contactform-code.php`.

Show us where do you build this `div` and you will have the place where you have to pass the `id`.

**Edit:**

Well, I finally get your problem. You have one popup define on your page that can be called on each click from each row. And you want to know how to pass the row id to the global popup.

This can be done in javascript. Instead of :

```
<a href='javascript:fg_popup_form("fg_formContainer","fg_form_InnerContainer","fg_backgroundpopup" );'>
  <?php echo utilities::getStatusCode($submissionObject->getCandidateStatus()); ?>
</a>
```

You can better use :

```
<a href="#" class="popup_contact">
  <?php echo utilities::getStatusCode($submissionObject->getCandidateStatus()); ?>
</a>
<!-- use this hidden span to put the row id, to be able to retrieve it using jQuery -->
<span class="row_id" style="display: none">
  <?php echo $referral->getId() ?>
</span>
```

And then, define an action using jQuery (for example):

```
$('.popup_contact').click(function() {
  // put the row id into the hidden field in the popup
  var rowId = $(this).parent().find('span.row_id').html();
  $('#submitted').val(rowId);

  fg_popup_form("fg_formContainer", "fg_form_InnerContainer", "fg_backgroundpopup");
  return false;
})
```

Comment: I was trying not to use Doctrine_Core in my model; I'm glad you showed me how to do that as well.  Thanks.  Regarding the other, I've updated the original question to include the contents of contactform-code.php

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far.  I'm a little unclear as to where the jQuery action would be placed.  In a script tag in the head of the page where <a href="#" class="popup_contact"> is defined?

Comment: If so, by doing so, it broke the popup completely.  The popup doesn't get pulled up at all.  BTW: you are correct, you do understand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Your action does place a pretty little "#" in my url though.  :)

Comment: By commenting out these lines: var rowId = $(this).next('span.row_id').val();
  $('#submitted').val(rowId);  I was able to get the popup back, so the call to the popup works, it's just something in the above two lines that it doesn't like.

Comment: I've put a `return false` at the end of the function to avoid the `#` in the url and also fixed the `rowId` (I wrote it without testing it). By the way, I don't know the html id of the hiddne field in your popup, that's why I put the `#submitted`. Feel free to change it and it should works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; just returned from vacation. Just implemented your changes, and no go.  No popup and the '#' still gets placed in the url.

Comment: I suspect that something isn't being passed (or retrieved) to/from the the actual rendered form since there are several 'includes' being used here. What's your thought?

Comment: This error came up: 'Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function'

Comment: Oh I see, I used `$` because it's easy to browse dom using jQuery. `$` is provided by jQuery. I guess you didn't use jQuery in your page so it's not loaded. Can you include it or you don't want to use it ?

Comment: It's loaded and being used (I use it for other things on the page).

Comment: Hum strange. Try to use `jQuery` instead of `$`. Check [this working](http://jsfiddle.net/GrhHu/1/) example (without the popup management).

Comment: If I comment out the popup management line, per your example, the error goes away, but obviously so does everything else.

Comment: Well, I can't go futher.. Here is a [working example with the popup](http://jsfiddle.net/GrhHu/2/). The `submitted` field in not hidden to see the change made by the js. It goes from `1` to `56`.

Comment: Edit.  Okay, I see what you were having me do... I changed it to test it, and the "$" error goes away, but I get another one in it's place. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.  ...and as far as location, it's showing the error right before the closing tag of the </script>

Comment: I understand.  Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Then it is something else than the subject of this question :)

Comment: I'm sure you are right.  Again, thanks.  I'll accept your answer, because it does work on your working example (just not mine). I'll report back if I ever get it working on my end.

Comment: I hate to bother you again, but I'm still struggling with this.  I've copied your working example word for word and placed it into my index page, and it is still failing to do anything other than place a '#' in the url.  Do you have any recommendations on how to troubleshoot this?  Do you think this might be a jQuery problem? Alos, after coping your code word for word, I don't even get any errors in my javascript console on chrome. ...I'm stumped.  ... and frustrated.

Comment: Can you upload it somewhere so I can check it directly?

Comment: ...finally got it working. :)  Your code was correct all along.  I had multiple jQuery conflicts.  Once that was corrected, your code worked beautifully.  Thanks for all the help.